# How to remove a property from object returned from SQLAlchemy query without deleting from database?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I would like to remove a file from a 'project' before adding it to a list and returning the projects from the server. If I just change file to None however, it is deleted from the database.

```
projects = models.Project.query.filter_by(uid=uid).all()
for p in projects:
   p.file = None
   projects_list.append(p.serialize)

return json.dumps(projects_list, default=datetime_converter), 200
```

How can i interact with the objects returned from the query without effecting the db?

Comment: After you loop through your query results and build your `projects_list` could you not just `.rollback` the changes to the objects and then `return` the result from your function?

Comment: As suggested you could simply roll back.  If that's too hacky, I would be inclined to have `Project.serialize` handle it, by explicitly including only the desired attributes in its output.